# Is there a way to run a web browser in Android in background mode? And finalize it?

Tags: java, android

I'd need to do that for the application I'm building right now, as strange at it would sound, if it could be stopped after some time has passed (let's say a pair of minutes) it would be even better, but if it cannot be done I don't think it's that big of a deal as I guess memory freeing service of Android can take care of this.

Anyway I've tried the following code

```
final URI uri= URI:parse("http://www.google.com");    
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
context.setActivity(intent);
}
}).start();
```

And the browser starts but not in the background, it's completely shown, I've tried to exchange ACTION_VIEW for ACTION_USER_BACKGROUND, but with that the application fails.

Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I've developed an application that adds results depending on the contents of the url, it's easier for me to launch a browser with the right content that try to develop a communication between every aspect of my application and Android, that's the reason.

Comment: This won't work, starting an activity via an intent will always start it as a foreground activity regarless of whatever thread you use to send the intent.

Comment: If this "communication" depends on something like the above, you're doing it wrong. What are you *really* trying to achieve?